# Display HOG feature inside Label using PYQT5 python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, pyqt5

I am trying to display extracted features from an Image  using **`Histogram of Oriented Gradients (HOG)`** on interface.
I need guidance how to display it; as for histogram we need to use **`(QWidget)`** and promote it to (Histogram class ) so how could I display histogram of oriented gradient to display extracted features
Any help in this case would be grateful

```
 hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor(qImg, (16,16), (8,8), (8,8), 9)
 hist = hog.compute(image)
 sample.append(hist)
 plt.plot(hist)
 plt.show()
```

I want to display HOG at interface ..for this I need guidance how to do that

Comment: show what you tried

Comment: @eyllanesc I wana know is it posible to display HOG in label ? or should I use Widget ?

Comment: Show how you create the HOG and then according to that I could indicate the appropriate option. Keep in mind that we are not much experts in image processing but if we could you know how to show it.

Comment: @eyllanesc please check I updated the question